# how to make upload file and folder/subfolder to dropbox using php

Tags: php, dropbox

i use dropphp for use upload file  to dropbox and works fine , but now i want upload file and folder/subfolder to dropbox , when folder/subfolder and files make same name in dropbox path location...

i found this code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15506402/how-to-copy-files-from-server-to-dropbox-using-php)

```
// Set the timezone so filenames are correct
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');

// Backup all files in public_html apart from the gz
$siteroot = "/path/to/backup";

$dropbox_email='dropbox@email';  //Dropbox username
$dropbox_pass='pass';   // Dropbox password

include("DropboxUploader.php");

$uploader = new DropboxUploader($dropbox_email, $dropbox_pass);

function FolderToDropbox($dir, $dropbox_link){    
    $dropbox_folder = 'FolderInDropboxRoot/';
    $files = scandir($dir);
    foreach($files as $item){
        if($item != '.' && $item != '..'){
            if(is_dir($dir.'/'.$item))     FolderToDropbox($dir.'/'.$item,$dropbox_link);
            else if(is_file($dir.'/'.$item)) {
                $clean_dir = str_replace("/path/to/backup", "", $dir);
                        $dropbox_link->upload($dir.'/'.$item,$dropbox_folder.$clean_dir.'/');  
            } 
        }
    }
    }

    FolderToDropbox($siteroot,$uploader);
```

but not work, maybe same change new api in

> dropboxuploader.php

How can the code be modified for [dropphp](https://github.com/f4bsch/DropPHP) or using dropbox SDK ?

thank you